# Python 2.7 CSV writer issue

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, csv

I have some Python code that lists pull requests in Github.  If I print the parsed json output to the console, I get the expected results, but when I output the parsed json to a csv file, I'm not getting the same results.  They are cut off after the sixth result (and that varies).

What I'm trying to do is overwrite the csv each time with the latest output.

Also, I'm dealing with unicode output which I use unicodecsv for. I don't know if this is throwing the csv output off.

I will list both instances of the relevant piece of code with the print statement and with the csv code.

Thanks for any help.

```
import sys
import codecs
sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stdout)
sys.stderr = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stderr)
import csv
import unicodecsv

for pr in result:
    data = pr.as_dict()
    changes = (gh.repository('my-repo', repo).pull_request(data['number'])).as_dict()   
    if changes['commits'] == 1 and changes['changed_files'] == 1:
        #keep print to console for testing purposes
        print "Login: " + changes['user']['login'] + '\n' + "Title: " + changes['title'] + '\n' + "Changed Files: " + str(changes['changed_files']) + '\n' + "Commits: " + str(changes['commits']) + '\n'
```

With csv:

```
import sys
import codecs
sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stdout)
sys.stderr = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stderr)
import csv
import unicodecsv
for pr in result:
    data = pr.as_dict()
    changes = (gh.repository('my-repo', repo).pull_request(data['number'])).as_dict()   
    if changes['commits'] == 1 and changes['changed_files'] == 1:
       with open('c:\pull.csv', 'r+') as f:
            csv_writer = unicodecsv.writer(f, encoding='utf-8')
            csv_writer.writerow(['Login', 'Title', 'Changed files', 'Commits'])
            for i in changes['user']['login'], changes['title'], str(changes['changed_files']), str(changes['commits']) :
                csv_writer.writerow([changes['user']['login'], changes['title'],changes['changed_files'], changes['commits']])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the way you write data to file.
Every time you `open` file in `r+` mode you will overwrite the last written rows.
And for dealing with [JSON](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#saving-structured-data-with-json)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I have changed the way I call the file to open.  I used `w` and now I get a single letter per column.  The content is being pulled as dictionary content (using the github3.py library).  Right now I'm lost as how to proceed. Again, my logic may be off, but if I open the file for writing outside the loop, it should just open the file once, and then proceed to write the data (sort of like the print statement is iterating through and printing the correct data to the console)?? Any further help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please disregard my last reply.  You are absolutely, correct, it's the mode in which I'm opening the file as it actually is in a loop (slapping myself in the head!!).  Thanks!!

Comment: Opening the file in `ab+` mode looks like it gets mostly what I want, but it appends the file from the end.  I would like to open the file (create if it doesn't exist) and append starting from the beginning, essentially erasing the content and writing new data in append mode.  Please let me know if this requires a separate question.  Thanks!

Comment: Looks like I will have to open it outside the loop for reading and writing and then append inside the loop...